# Oracle SQL max from different rows

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I have the table

```
ID - A - B
----------
1  - 5 - 2
1  - 3 - 7
2  - 1 - 8
2  - 4 - 6
...
```

which query returns one single row for every different ID like this:

```
1  - 5 - 7
2  - 4 - 8
```

(extracting max values from column A and column B for every specific ID)

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `MAX()`.

Comment: `SELECT id, MAX(A), MAX(B) FROM your_tab GROUP BY id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select id, max(A), max(B)
    from table1
    group by id
```